# Como Customizar as Setas do Simple Paginator?

Tags: laravel

É muito bom usar a paginação do Laravel, com um comando se faz tudo:

#### Controller

```
$artigos->simplePaginate(5);
```

#### View

```
{!! $artigos->render !!}
```

E depois disso é gerada a paginação.

Mas por default vem com as setas de **PREV** e **NEXT**.

Como tirar elas e colocar **Anterior** e **Próximo** ?

E por default também essa paginação é customizada com classes do Bootstrap. Mas eu não estou usando bootstrap e isso vale para outros desenvolvedores também que não usam.

Comment: Qual versão do Laravel?

Comment: Larave 5.0, 5.1, 5.2. Eu vi que o Laravel 5.3 tem um esquema bem legal como já comentado.

Comment: Sim, o Laravel já é incrível, e o 5.3 está ainda melhor...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem um jeito simples que isso pode ser feito. Visto que o Paginate do Laravel é baseado no tema do Bootstrap é possível alterar seus valores pelo `str_replace()` do PHP.

```
<?php
   $pagination = $artigos->render();
   $pagination = str_replace('&laquo;', 'POSTS RECENTES <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>', $pagination);
   $pagination = str_replace('&raquo;', '<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> MAIS POSTS', $pagination);

   echo $pagination;
?>
```

Esse caracter `&laquo;` («) é a seta para esquerda padrão que o Laravel configurou para o `prev` e o outro caracter `&raquo;` (») o padrão para direita.

Então é só fazer um `str_replace()`, substituindo a seta pelo que quisermos, um botão, **anterior**, **próximo**.

Answer (score 5):

### De acordo com a documentação do [Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view) é possível personalizar a view da seguinte forma:

**Rodando o comando do `artisan` para transportar a `view` padrão da paginação para `resources/views/vendor/pagination`:**

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

---

**A partir daí, basta editar o conteúdo `HTML` do seu `default.blade.php`, que corresponde a paginação padrão.**

---

**Ainda segundo a documentação, você pode personalizar as próprias funcionalidades da `view` utilizando os seguintes métodos:**

```
$results->count()
$results->currentPage()
$results->firstItem()
$results->hasMorePages()
$results->lastItem()
$results->lastPage() (Not available when using simplePaginate)
$results->nextPageUrl()
$results->perPage()
$results->previousPageUrl()
$results->total() (Not available when using simplePaginate)
$results->url($page)
```

- Note que no caso da sua pergunta, usando `simplePaginate()`, alguns métodos não estão disponíveis!

---

### Para paginação no [Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination) e anterior

**Basta que ao invés de utilizar o método `render()`, faça da seguinte forma:**

```
@include('paginacao.default', ['paginator' => $artigos]) //onde o primeiro parâmetro é o caminho da sua view
```

**E personalizar a mesma criando o seu blade, por exemplo:**

```
@if ($paginator->lastPage() > 1)
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="{{ ($paginator->currentPage() == 1) ? ' disabled' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ $paginator->url(1) }}">Previous</a>
    </li>
    @for ($i = 1; $i <= $paginator->lastPage(); $i++)
        <li class="{{ ($paginator->currentPage() == $i) ? ' active' : ''     }}">
            <a href="{{ $paginator->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a>
        </li>
    @endfor
    <li class="{{ ($paginator->currentPage() == $paginator->lastPage()) ? ' disabled' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ $paginator->url($paginator->currentPage()+1) }}" >Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
@endif
```

**Onde para esta versão os métodos disponíveis são:**

```
$results->count()
$results->currentPage()
$results->firstItem()
$results->hasMorePages()
$results->lastItem()
$results->lastPage() (Not available when using simplePaginate)
$results->nextPageUrl()
$results->perPage()
$results->previousPageUrl()
$results->total() (Not available when using simplePaginate)
$results->url($page)
```